# `findall` from a vector of CartesianIndices in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

`CI` is the given vector. Each element is `CartesianIndex`.

```
julia> CI
5-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:                                     
 CartesianIndex(1, 3, 1)                                                
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)                                                 
 CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3)                                                 
 CartesianIndex(1, 2, 4)                                                 
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)
```

I want to find elements in CI for which the `d`-th element is `k`. Let `f(CI,d,k)` be such a function.

```
julia> f(CI,1,2)
[CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3) ]

julia> f(CI,2,1)
[CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4), CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)]
```

How can I define such a function `f`?
I guess a naive way is converting `CI` to a matrix array, then use `findall` function. But I feel there is a more clever way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways in Julia to accomplish this task. Here are a few examples:

One method of [the `filter` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.filter) takes as its first argument an arbitrary unary function that is passed each element of the collection in question and, if the function returns `false`, removes that element from the collection. [`CartesianIndex` values can be indexed like `Tuple`s](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndex), so use this to find which elements of `CI` have a value of `value` in dimension `d`:

```
julia> CI = [CartesianIndex(1,3,1), CartesianIndex(1,1,4), CartesianIndex(2,2,3), CartesianIndex(1,2,4), CartesianIndex(1,1,1)]
5-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 3, 1)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3)
 CartesianIndex(1, 2, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)

julia> CI[2]
CartesianIndex(1, 3, 1)

julia> CI[2][1]
1

julia> filter(idx -> idx[2] == 1, CI)
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)

julia> f1(ci, d, value) = filter(idx -> idx[d] == value, ci)
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f1(CI, 1, 2)
1-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3)

julia> f1(CI, 2, 1)
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)
```

You can even use [the in-place `filter!` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.filter!) to avoid allocating and returning a copy of the input array (assuming you do not need the array again later):

```
julia> CIcopy = copy(CI)
5-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 3, 1)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3)
 CartesianIndex(1, 2, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)

julia> f1!(ci, d, value) = filter!(idx -> idx[d] == value, ci)
f1! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f1!(CIcopy, 2, 1)
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)

julia> CIcopy  # proving it was modified in place
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)
```

[The `findall` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findall-Tuple%7BFunction,%20Any%7D) can be used like `filter`, but it will be slower due to the temporary array that has to be constructed in the process:

```
julia> findall(idx -> idx[2] == 1, CI)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 5

julia> f2(ci, d, value) = ci[findall(idx -> idx[d] == value, ci)]
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(CI, 1, 2)
1-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3)

julia> f2(CI, 2, 1)
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)
```

You can also [broadcast](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting) the [`getindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.getindex) method and the `==` operator and use [logical indexing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Logical-indexing) of vectors to the same effect:

```
julia> getindex(CI[1], 2)
3

julia> getindex.(CI, 2)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 1
 2
 2
 1

julia> getindex.(CI, 2) .== 1
5-element BitVector:
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1

julia> f3(ci, d, value) = ci[getindex.(ci, Ref(d)) .== value]
f3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f3(CI, 1, 2)
1-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(2, 2, 3)

julia> f3(CI, 2, 1)
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{3}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Can we use filter function istead of findall?

Comment: @Sakurai.JJ Yes `filter` would be even better, and significantly faster, since it doesn't create an intermediate temporary array: `filter(idx -> idx[d] == value, ci)`, or working in-place, `filter!(idx -> idx[d] == value, ci)`

Comment: May I ask the reason why `filter` is faster than `findall`?

Comment: I just updated my comment, but the main reason is probably that it directly creates the output array, instead of first creating an index vector and then building the final vector from that. This is a general theme in performance computing, avoid intermediate objects unless needed, directly calculate your desired output instead.

Comment: Thank you for that information. It was so helpful.

Comment: BTW, @PaSTE, if you like, you can just update your answer to include the `filter` solution.

Comment: Answer updated with the better solution.

Comment: Thanks, @PaSTE, your answer was helpful.